# How to redirect user to another page when logged into Firebase Auth in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a web page with the Firebase Auth services for javascript (web). In my `index.html` is the login:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index Page</title>
    <!-- The Firebase JS SDK and SDKs for Firebase products are here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="loginContainer">
        <div id="titleContainer">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="elementsContent">
            <input class="txtBox" id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button class="btn btn-action" id="btnLogin">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <!-- The Firebase JS SDK and SDKs for Firebase products are here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formContainer">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
        <button id="btnLogout" class="btn hide">Logout</button>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {

// My web app's Firebase configuration are here -------------------

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// References
var database = firebase.database();
var auth = firebase.auth();

// Get elements
const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
const btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');

// Add login event
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Get email and pass
    database.ref('emailChild').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var email = snapshot.val();
        console.log(email);
        const pass = txtPassword.value;
        // Sign in
        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    });
});

btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {
    auth.signOut();
});

// Add event listener
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
        console.log(user);
    } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
    }
});

}());
```

What I want to do and I don't know how to do it is the following:

1. When you log in, redirect to the `main.html` page.
2. In `main.html` I have a button to log out. I would like the button to redirect to `index.html`.

In my login there is only the textbox for the password, the email I retrieved from the database and there is no option to sign up. I am the only user (just to put the code in context).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using location.href = 'url'

After signing up successfully redirect to index page using

location.href = 'main.html'

You should do that after promise is resolved like so.
promise.then(() => { location.href = 'main.html' }

Similarly after clicking the logout button

location.href = 'index.html'

!!! Take care of the relative and absolute urls

Comment: I have to put that after `promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));`?

Comment: const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);

promise.then(() => location.href = 'main.html').catch(e => console.log(e.message));

Comment: I am having an error in the console that says: `Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. The error comes from this line: `btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e => {`
For what is this?

Comment: because you did not select the button - store the reference to the button element first:
const btnLogout = document.getElementById('idofbtn')
then btnLogout.addEventListener....so and so

Comment: In my `app.js` file I did it as you indicate. But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: please inbox me at messenger for more detailed discussion so that I can help you fix it.